# Kotlin - How to avoid casting of second variable in when() statement of a sealed class

Tags: kotlin

I have a sealed class representing field types:

```
sealed class FieldDef {
    object StringField: FieldDef()
    class ListField(val element: FieldDef): FieldDef()
    class MapField(val children: Map<String, FieldDef>): FieldDef()

    // ... more field types
}
```

And I have a function that processes a pair of fields definitions.

```
    fun processSameTypes(fd1: FieldDef, fd2: FieldDef) {
        if (fd1::class == fd2::class) {
            when (fd1) {
                is MapField -> processMaps(fd1, (fd2 as MapField))
                is ListField -> processLists(fd1, (fd2 as ListField))
            }
        }
    }
```

The code as written is correct - given the logic the casts of the fd2 variable will always succeed.

But I feel there should be a way to express this without the cast, however if I try to remove the cast I get the error:

```
Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is FieldDef but FieldDef.ListField was expected
```

Is there a better way to handle this such that I can remove the cast (the cast is not necessary).

If there is no better way of solving this, could you explain why the compiler is unable to infer the correct type of the `fd2` variable. My logic here is that since the `when` is protected by the outer `if` and that `FieldDef` is a sealed class the compiler should be able to infer the type of `fd2`.

Kotlin Version: 1.5.30 (JVM)

**Edit: Conclusion**

I think it's fair to say that passing a class object around is idiomatic Java (and through its heritage Kotlin too), specifically that it is the way of representing types at Runtime. Hence it is something I would like to see the Kotlin compiler support in the future.

That said, it doesn't support it today, so I agree with @TreffnonX - that just sucking it up and throwing in the cast is the best solution - hence I am not going to change my code.

However I did ask for a way to solve the problem without using a cast and @Sweeper provided one - so I will accept that answer.

Comment: The compiler simply isn’t that sophisticated. They have to draw the line somewhere on how many potential lines of logic and how deep it should check for smart casting. Everything costs compile time and complexity in the compiler. Remember the compiler is constantly rerunning as you type to give you immediate feedback. There are some unchecked casts in the standard library for situations like this.

Comment: The pattern matching doesnt derive anything from this equality check. For your expectation to succeed, the compiler would have to create an 'entity entanglement' within the if clause, and only dynamically infer the type of fd2, whenever the type of fd1 is bound to be either `MapField` or `ListField`. I do not believe such entanglements exist in the compiler. As given by Sweeper, there are ideas to work around this, but they all seem more effort than simply casting in this case. If you had some 20 cases to separate, I would argue that a more elegant solution was justified, but ont in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give an argument to `when`, so that you can check the types of multiple things.

```
// Now you can remove "if (fd1::class == fd2::class)" too
when {
    fd1 is FieldDef.MapField && fd2 is FieldDef.MapField -> 
        processMaps(fd1, fd2)
    fd1 is FieldDef.ListField && fd2 is FieldDef.ListField -> 
        processLists(fd1, fd2)
}
```

Alternatively, create your own inline function for checking both:

```
inline fun <reified TTarget> checkBothTypes(a: Any, b: Any, block: (TTarget, TTarget) -> Unit) {
    if (a is TTarget && b is TTarget) {
        block(a, b)
    }
}
```

Another way of writing this, to allow returning a result from the block:

```
inline fun <reified TTarget, TResult> checkBothTypes(
    type: KClass<TTarget>, a: Any, b: Any, block: (TTarget, TTarget) -> TResult
): TResult? {
    if (a is TTarget && b is TTarget) {
        return block(a, b)
    }
    return null
}
```

Usage:

```
checkBothTypes<FieldDef.ListField>(fd1, fd2) { l1, l2 ->
    processLists(l1, l2) // or use a function reference
    // ...
}
checkBothTypes<FieldDef.MapField>(fd1, fd2) { m1, m2 ->
    processMaps(m1, m2) // or use a function reference
    // ...
}
```

If you want to get a result from all the checks, use `?:` to chain the calls together, creating a single expression.

Note that unlike when using `when(...)`, these approaches cannot detect a missing check for a subclass of `FieldDef`.